# Number of methods not the same between keeping the whole package and keeping individual class in ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

I'm using ProGuard to shrink down a 3rd party lib that I used in my app. When I config ProGuard to keep the whole package `-keep class com.nexstreaming.nexplayerengine.** { *; }`, I got 40496 methods in my APK and the application works fine. However, when I keep individual classes from that methods (all of them, e.g. `-keep class com.nexstreaming.nexplayerengine.GLRender { *; }`, etc.), I got only 40460 and the app crash whenever I navigate to the part that utilize the lib. I really need some explanation. (Btw, sorry for the bad English)